# The menu item is not deleted on WordPress

Tags: menus, add-menu-page

Doing a WP project and stumbling over commonplace things. The menu item is not deleted.

Video [demonstrate](https://biblsoft.ru/images/monopics/2021-06-04_21-02-42.mp4) this problem

[image: Problem with wp menu item deleting]

What could be the reason?

Comment: past questions that have similar issues with this interface have been caused by code/data that uses incorrect capitalisation, e.g. a post type of `test` but the database column contains `Test`, e.g. when someone renamed a post type in code after creating menu items, however there are lots of other things this could be. Also your question _must_ be self-contained, I won't remove the link offsite myself, but you should edit it out and replace it with an embedded version or an equivalent that describes the question

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the theme has a code that creates the menu item.